# How do I programmatically enable a microphone in a web app, without any user tapping?

Tags: dialogflow-es, speech-to-text, microphone

I'm building a basic web app using Firebase. My goal is to have the user interact with my app only using their voice, without any tapping whatsoever.

I'm using GCP's DialogFlow to register the intent (e.g. "Hey web app"), however I need to programmatically (or manually) always have the device microphone on listening for that intent. All the resources I've seen require a click/touch of the microphone icon first, which is not what I'm after.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd imagine that allowing microphone access without some sort of prompt would be really problematic.

Comment: Could you please clarify your imagination?